# Regarding app Submission on itunes store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, crash-reports

I am submitted the application on itunes connect few days ago, and i did not check the option of 'include app symbols for your application to receive symbolicate crash logs from apple' at substitution time, now i am not getting proper crash report.

dose 'include app symbols for your application to receive symbolicate crash logs from apple' is mandatory for get crash reports.

Comment: see this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes, As per Apple document. Ref [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect/UploadingYourApptoiTunesConnect.html)

> If you include symbols when uploading your app to iTunes Connect,
>   Apple collects and aggregates crash data on user devices for you.
>   Later, you can view these crash reports in the Crashes organizer,
>   described in [Analyzing Crash Reports](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH21-SW1)

Answer (score 1):

Here you will get your Answer

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AnalyzingCrashReports/AnalyzingCrashReports.html